Error: Firebase app initialized multiple times. Python
Okay so I get this error saying:
ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.

I understand this says that the firebase app is being initialized more that once but I dont understand where exactly I'm doing it.
Ok so here are my modules of code in python:
homeScreen.Py:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

class HomeScreen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, username):
        super().__init__()
        self.cred = credentials.Certificate("mykey.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(self.cred)
        self.db = firestore.client()
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.initUI()
        self.cipher = Fernet('mykey')

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Home')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 700, 500)
        greeting_message = "Hello " + self.name + ". Good username: " + self.username
        self.info = QLabel(greeting_message, self)
        self.info.setGeometry(20, 20, 400, 50)
        self.font = QFont()
        self.font.setPointSize(20)
        self.info.setFont(self.font)

And here is my base.py:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from login import *
from signup import *


class Options(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('h')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 700, 500)
        self.login_b = QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.login_b.setGeometry(250, 150, 100, 50)
        self.login_b.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.signup_b = QPushButton('Sign Up', self)
        self.signup_b.setGeometry(250, 210, 100, 50)
        self.signup_b.clicked.connect(self.signup)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def login(self):
        self.login_window = Login() 
        self.login_window.show()
        self.close()
    def signup(self):
        self.signup_window = SignUp() 
        self.signup_window.show()
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Options()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

And at last here is my sign up.py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64
from homeScreen import *

class SignUp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.cipher = Fernet('mykey')
        self.cred = credentials.Certificate("mypath.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(self.cred)
        self.db = firestore.client()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Sign Up')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 700, 500)
        self.info = QLabel('Sign Up', self)
        self.info.setGeometry(360, 100, 200, 50)
        self.font = QFont()
        self.font.setPointSize(20)
        self.info.setFont(self.font) 
        self.name_t = QLineEdit(self)
        self.name_t.setGeometry(300, 150, 200, 30)
        self.name_t.setPlaceholderText("Full Name")
        self.username_t = QLineEdit(self)
        self.username_t.setGeometry(300, 200, 200, 30)
        self.username_t.setPlaceholderText("Username")
        self.password_t = QLineEdit(self)
        self.password_t.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password_t.setGeometry(300, 240, 200, 30)
        self.password_t.setPlaceholderText("Password")
        self.submit_b = QPushButton('Submit', self)
        self.submit_b.setGeometry(300, 280, 200, 50)
        self.submit_b.clicked.connect(self.submit_info)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def submit_info(self):
        password_bytes = self.password_t.text().encode()
        encrypted_password = base64.b64encode(self.cipher.encrypt(password_bytes)).decode()
        self.db.collection('users').add({'name': self.name_t.text(), 'username': self.username_t.text(), 'password': encrypted_password})
        self.login_window = HomeScreen(self.name_t.text(), self.username_t.text()) 
        self.login_window.show()
        self.close()

Please comment for any further clarification

it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
wildcard imports pollute the namespace.

A simple text search will show that initialize_app is called in two places. The error message is self-explanatory.

But then in each class I only initialize firebase once
